# Error when testing Laravel controller with mockery: Call to a member function fetchMock() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, mockery

I receive the following error when making a PHPUnit test with Mockery (dev-master) of the controller in Laravel 4.2 :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchMock() on a non-object in \laravel\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery.php on line 129**

The controller and test are as follows:

```
class UserControllerTest extends TestCase {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'User');
  }
  function tearDown() {
    Mockery::close();
  }
  public function testIndex() {
    $this->mock
      ->shouldReceive('all')
      ->once()
      ->andReturn('foo');
    $this->app->instance('User', $this->mock);
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'UserController@index');
    //other stuff
  }
}

class UserController extends \BaseController {
  protected $user;
  public function __construct(User $user) {
    $this->user = $user;
  }
  public function index() {
    $users = $this->user->all();
    return View::make('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
  }
  //other stuff
}
```

This test works ok without Mockery (i.e. without executing `$this->app->instance('User', $this->mock);` )

The error is raised inside **fetchMock** function, when executing
`return self::$_container->fetchMock($name);`

Here are the values visible in debugger inside fetchMock when it fails:

[image]

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `__construct` method using this and try again:

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'User');
}
```